# Can't convert column varchar to int

Tags: sql-server, int, varchar

I have column of `varchar` data type with values like `5/3/2012`. I want to convert into int as `2016-05-03`. When I'm trying to do so, it is returning null as output

```
cast(convert(varchar(10), '5/3/2012', 112) as int)
```

Comment: `2016-05-03` is a `Date` not a `Integer` value

Answer (score 1):

`2016-05-03` is a `Date` not a `Integer` value. So you need to convert it to `Date`

You just want to `Convert` it to `Date` with style `101`

```
Select convert(Date, '5/3/2012', 101) --2012-05-03
```

Comment: Prdp I Need it to load into a column as int rather than date

Comment: @user2667326 - `Int` cannot store `-`

Answer (score 0):

But if you truly do need to convert it to an INT, try this -

```
DECLARE @d DATE = '5/3/2012'
DECLARE @y int = YEAR( @d )
    , @m int = MONTH( @d )
    , @dy int = DAY( @d )

SELECT CAST(concat( @y, format(@m, '00'), format(@dy,'00')) as int)
```

Comment: Did you see this `I want to convert into int as 2016-05-03`.. even am surprised

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT CONVERT(INT,convert(Datetime, '5/3/2012', 101))
--41030
```

Comment: Add more details to the answer